# Convert CLLocationCoordinate2D and radius into zoom and central point of GMSMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have got a screen with squared in the center with an offset of y coordinate and fixed-width, I need to save coordinate and radius of squared and send it to the server, after that, I need to restore screen state.
First part was easy:

```
let radius:CGFloat = 200
let centerYCoordinate:CGFloat = (self.view.bounds.size.height/2)-30

let left = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: CGPoint.init(x: (self.view.bounds.size.width/2)-radius, y: centerYCoordinate-radius))
let right = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: CGPoint.init(x: (self.view.bounds.size.width/2)+radius, y: centerYCoordinate-radius))
let center = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: CGPoint.init(x: (self.view.bounds.size.width/2), y: centerYCoordinate))
let leftLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: left.latitude, longitude: left.longitude)
let rightLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: right.latitude, longitude: right.longitude)
let distance = leftLocation.distance(from: rightLocation)
```

But I can not find any possible things how to restore state by center coordinate and radius, anyone has any ideas?

edit: i find way to calculate zoom

```
let radius:CGFloat = 200 
let screenWidhtInPoints: CGFloat = radius*2
let zoom = GMSCameraPosition.zoom(at: location, forMeters: distance, perPoints: screenWidhtInPoints)
```

but how can i make offset of y coordinate center by 30 points ?